# Compare values with 3 states Y/N as String or DbNull

Tags: vb.net, operators, dbnull

I have database table with a column `DECISION` which can have the following values:`'Y'`,`'N'`, or `(null)`. There can be multiple people updating the values in this database table via an application.

I want to ensure that the `DataGridView` which displays this information is kept up to date for all users regularly.

I have a background thread which does the following:

```
For Each new_row As DataRow In dsData.Tables("Progress").Rows
    For Each cur_row As DataRow In dsData.Tables("List").Rows
        If new_row("SEQ") = cur_row("SEQ") And new_row("DECISION") <> cur_row("DECISION") Then
            cur_row("DECISION") = new_row("DECISION")
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Essentially `dsData.Tables("Progress")` is populated with the latest data and then compared to the current values in the `DataGridView` column, based on a sequence number `SEQ`.

What I want to happen is that if they are different, the `cur_row` value is changed to that of `new_row`.

However, it falls over because sometimes it tries to compare a string `'N'` or `'Y'` with `(null)` which can't be done.

What is the best way to work around this?

I do want to compare and update any `(null)` as it is a genuine state in this system.

Comment: First things first, you should not be making changes to a `DataTable` in a secondary thread if it's bound to a control because that means that you're changing the UI from that secondary thread.

Comment: Is there really any point to the comparison? Why not just set the value? If they are already equal then it will have no effect so you lose nothing except perhaps a few milliseconds. You can just check that the new value isn't null and, if not, update the current value with the new value. That will change the current value if they are different and have no effect if they're already the same.

Comment: That's actually a really good point. I more or less assumed it would be more efficient to only update the values for the instances where they were different, but perhaps the overhead won't matter too much in reality. 

The updating of the UI is done thread-safely. I've simplified my code to focus on the issue and only mentioned that it was a separate thread for context.

Comment: It definitely will be more efficient to only update those fields that will change but the difference may be negligible. That said, if you're switching threads to update each time, that will increase the overhead.  Given that you mat still want to test for null anyway, so that you don't replace an existing value with null, and testing is fairly simple anyway, you probably ought to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TryCast` operator can help you here.  You can try to cast as type `String` and a field containing `DBNull.Value` will simply return `Nothing`.

```
Dim cur_val = TryCast(cur_row("DECISION"), String)
Dim new_val = TryCast(new_row("DECISION"), String)

If new_val IsNot Nothing AndAlso cur_val <> new_val Then
    cur_row("DECISION") = new_val
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be the best method. I'll play around a bit.